# Draw Text in an ImageView

Tags: android, canvas

I have a Nine-Patch Image in an ImageView and want to draw text into the content area of the image.
Android will stretch the image and on different screens I cant work with units like dp or px. It's too inaccurate.

How to accomplish this mission? =)

Comment: use TextView with background as your 9patch image.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom `ImageView` and in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method you can draw text on it the following way:

```
Paint paint = new Paint()
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(11);
canvas.drawText("your text", x, y, paint);
```

You can center the text on your `ImageView` for example:

```
int imgWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
int imgHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
float txtWidth = paint.measureText("your text");

int x = imgWidth/2 - txtWidth/2;
int y = imgHeight/2 - 6; // 6 is half of the text size
```

Comment: But then I still have the problem with the pixels, that the text is not there where it should be.

Comment: I updated my answer with a brief example on positioning the text. You dont have to bother with density, since you are always computing the position with the actual pixel values.

Comment: You should not set up `Paint` in the `OnDraw()` method due to performance. It's also a good idea to use `TextPaint` instead of only `Paint` for the case that you need to ellipsize your text with `TextUtils.ellipsize()`.